# An error occurs when creating a lower version react-native

Tags: react-native

I tried to use react-native-beacons-manger to use beacons in react native, but I got an error. So I try to create lower version react-native and run. But it made an error.

```
$ react-native init BeaconTest --version 0.59.0

$ react-native run-ios

An error looks like
Failed to load bundle(http://localhost:801/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false with error:(Could not connect to development server)
```

[image]

my package.json file

```
{

  "name": "BeaconTest",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.0"
  },

  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.7.2",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.57.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
  },

  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

I also tried

$ react-native init Test
$ npm install react-native@0.59.0

but it also made some errors

please let me know how to create low version react-native so that I can use beacon package (react-native-beacons-managers)

Comment: It has nothing to do with react native version.Please close bundle and open project in xcode and try to run by pressing cmd+R

Comment: same error occurs on android and I also tried to run it in xcode and same error occurs. And when I opened the ios folder, there was no pod file. What is the problem?

Comment: pod file is introduced in latest react native version. so i must say please upgrade your project to 60 or >60 .All dependencies are auto linked

Comment: As above, I have to use react-native-beacons-manger to use the beacon feature, but above 0.60 I get an error.So I'm trying to use a lower version, but creating a lower version causes the above problem.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know how to user the lower version react-native. the right command was react-native start react-native run-ios. I solved the problem. Thanks